# Unwrapping a boost::function from boost::python::object with extract

Tags: c++, boost, boost-python, boost-function

How can I call C++ module functions from C++ but select the function from python?  See example below

I know I can setup a map of strings manually, and select the function I want to run, but I'd like a cleaner python solution.

I would also like it to be very efficient, hopefully by basically unwrapping the boost::python::object and extracting the boost::function<> out of it.

Here is the python file

```
import stackoverflow #this is a C++ module I wrote

t = stackoverflow.TestClass()
t.Reference()                      # time invoking a boost::function 100k times
t.CallSomeClassMemberFunction(t.a) # instead of choosing a function directly, i want to pass in which function I want to invoke from python
```

C++ module code (compiles, but does not run.. you can see my intent):

```
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <boost/function.hpp>
#include <boost/python.hpp>

struct TestClass
{
    TestClass() { }

    int a() const { return rand()%4; }
    int b() const { return rand()%64; }

    template<typename T>
    void BenchMark(T & aUnknownFunction)
    {
        timeval begin, end;
        long long sum(0);
        gettimeofday(&begin, NULL);
        __asm__ __volatile__ ("cpuid");
        for (int x(0); x!=100000; ++x)
            sum += aUnknownFunction();
        __asm__ __volatile__ ("cpuid");
        gettimeofday(&end, NULL);

        std::cout << "Time: " << 1000000 * (end.tv_sec - begin.tv_sec) + (end.tv_usec - begin.tv_usec) << std::endl;
        srand(sum);
    }

    void CallSomeClassMemberFunction(boost::python::object &aTest)
    {
        boost::function<int ()> unknownFunction =  boost::python::extract<boost::function<int ()> >(aTest) ;  // i don't think this works as I want
        BenchMark( unknownFunction );
    }

    void Reference()
    {
        boost::function<int ()> unknownFunction = boost::bind(&TestClass::a, this);
        BenchMark( unknownFunction );
    }
};


BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(stackoverflow)
{
    boost::python::class_<TestClass>("TestClass")
        .def("a",&TestClass::a)
        .def("b",&TestClass::b)
        .def("CallSomeClassMemberFunction",&TestClass::CallSomeClassMemberFunction)
        .def("Reference",&TestClass::Reference)
        ;
}
```

If you can get it to run, would love to see your timings as well.